# Formatting Coordinates from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, coordinates

I imported coordinates from Excel and now I'm trying to extract the specific information I need.
For longitude I need values between 20 to 30 degrees, and latitude I need -50to -40
The Latitude and Longitude Values are in different columns and the methods I'm using result in error, which I'm not understanding how to get around.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
import xlwt
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excelpath=filepath
fileplace=os.path.join(excelpath, filename)
exl=pd.ExcelFile(fileplace)
workbook=exl.parse("Sheet1")
Lat=workbook['Latitude']
Long=workbook['Longitude']
Coords=list(zip(Lat,Long))
Newlist=[]
for value in Coords:
    if Lat.between(-50,-40) and Long.between(20,30):
         Newlist.append(Coords)
```

What can I do to fix this? The error I get is The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What's the error? Any sample data?

Comment: The error is "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." and some example data is like ((80,10) , (-45,25) , (-60, 10) , (-80,40))

Comment: Is Try to do : `print(Lat.between(-50,-40))` d u get a list ... Or a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) value? `If` & `and `need boolean value to evaluate.